# Can VkSemaphore be used in host-device synchronization

Tags: graphics, vulkan

My project is something like game engine or modeling software. It has a "viewport" widget (an ImGui window, in my case) to show the scene. To render the widget, I first render an image for the scene, then use the image as a texture to map it to a quad area in the widget. After all widgets have been built, "frame" rendering begins. It uses all resources created before to render GUI and presents the frame.

Apparently, I need the command buffer for frame rendering to wait for the viewport rendering (image of scene). So, I create a new semaphore and let the command buffer for frame rendering wait for it besides the semaphore signaled by image acquration.

I think it is okay to not use a VkFence because the spec says, "A semaphore can be signaled after execution of a queue operation is completed, and a queue operation can wait for a semaphore to become signaled before it begins execution" so when the frame rendering begins, I assume that the preceding command buffer (the rendering for viewport) has been completed.

The code for rendering to too seperated, please consider the follow steps as an outline:

1. wait and reset fence for frame (this means the preceding frame rendering is finished, hence the rendering of viewport has been completed)
2. vkAcquireNextImageKHR(...)
3. reset and record viewport command buffer for current frame
4. submit viewport command buffer and let it signal viewport semaphore when it is done
5. reset and record frame command buffer
6. submit frame command buffer and let it waits for both image acquiration and viewport rendering before execution
7. present frame

Unfortunately, from the 2nd frame, when I reset the command buffer for the viewport, the validation layer tells me the command buffer is still in use. This issue can be fixed by simply adding a fence.

I do know the VkSemaphore is desgined for device synchronzation, but I think based on spec, the beginning of frame rendering proves that the viewport rendering has been finished, so my idea makes sense. I want to know why I can't assume the command buffer is completed, even if a corresponding semaphore has been waited for in later queue submission.

Comment: """My project needs to render a viewport firstly, then use the viewport to render the frame""" -- what do you mean by "viewport" and "frame"? Is this something similar to deferred rendering? I so, you can use renderpasses or subpasses. You still need to use fences for witing on the host until the device is done with the work.

Comment: @tuket I'm sorry, I have added more details on my project, please check the first paragraph. My point is that, if command buffer B depends on A by a semaphore, then the beginning of B can prove the finish of A. So I can reset A without any check. Am I wrong, why?

Comment: @SynchronizX: There's no reason to submit this as two batches of work. This should be submitted all at once with a single submit command. This also allows you to thread the creation of the two sets of command buffers, so that you don't have to do them in series.

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests a misunderstanding of how submitting works. The fact that you submit a series of batches that wait on a semaphore does *not* mean that, by the time that function returns, the wait on that semaphore has completed and the semaphore is signaled. Indeed, submitting something does not tell you *anything* about the state of the contents of what has been submitted (besides putting all CBs into the "pending" state).

While timeline semaphores do offer a way for the CPU to wait on semaphore signaling, the act of submission is *not* that mechanism. Submission is about giving a body of work to the GPU; it communicates nothing to the CPU directly. The CPU cannot assume anything based solely on submitting a batch of work (other than that the work will *eventually* be finished).

If the CPU wants to know how far the GPU has gotten, it needs to *ask* via some form of synchronization. Events, timeline semaphores, fences, the CPU must explicitly do something to synchronize itself with GPU operations.

Comment: I do understand queue submission tells nothing about state of command buffer. My assumption doesn't depend on this. Let's consider the easiest scenario: drawing a triangle. In the main loop, I first wait for a fence, then I should reset the fence, reset the command buffer, and acquire an image from swapchain, right?  The project add a new CB, which the CB for frame need to wait for it. My assumption doesn't get state of CB from submission, but from the fence for frame. The fence is signaled only if the frame rendering ends, which means the preceding task ends, so I think I can ensure the state

Comment: Your question says, "*This issue can be fixed by simply adding a fence.*". If that's the case, then you must not have had a fence somewhere. But you don't say *where* you added this fence. And since you did two submission operations, there are potentially two fences involved. So either your description of what you're doing doesn't match your code, or you're confused about which fences and CBs you're using.

Comment: @SynchronizX: Also, are you submitting these batches to the same queue?

Comment: The fence will be added right before the reset of CB, and yes, there is only one queue in my project. I should say, for now, there are only two submissions in my project: one for the "viewport", one for "frame", and the fence for frame is waited and reseted before all operations with vulkan in each cycle of mainloop, just like I said in the list above. That's why I am confused, because if the signal of final work tells me it is done, then anything before the final work should already be done.